# Area of a polar curve?

Tags: calculus

The question says :

> Find the area enclosed by the polar curve of the function
>   $r=8e^{0.9\theta}$, $0\leq\theta\leq \frac1 7$ and the straight line segment
>   between its ends.

I get how to find the area of the function but am confused on how to incorporate the straight line segment.

Comment: Did you try writing the straight line equation in cartesian coordinates and then converting to polar?

Comment: The usual integral over $\theta$ gives the area bounded by the curve and the lines joining its endpoints to the origin. So you just have to deduct the area of that triangle.

Comment: I'm still having trouble subtracting the area of the triangle. How exactly do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: the area of the triangle formed by the origin $(0,0)$ and the points with Cartesian coordinates $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is given by $$\frac 12\left|\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\end{matrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{matrix}c\\d\end{matrix}\right)\right|=\frac 12|ad-bc|$$

so you just have to convert the endpoints into Cartesian form